# Proving $\cos(\sin^{-1}x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, not sure about the intervals

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

During the preparation for my calculus course next semester I bumped into the question of proving $\cos(\sin^{-1}x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

---

**My prove:**

Now my idea to give a valid proof was the following, but I'm not sure if it's correct this way.

\begin{alignat}{2}
\cos(\sin^{-1}x) & = \sqrt{1-x^2} &\qquad&\\ 
\cos^2(\sin^{-1}x) & = 1-x^2 &&\text{squaring both sides}\\ 
1-\sin^2(\sin^{-1}x)& =1-x^2 &&\text{because} \cos^2(\theta)= 1 - \sin^{2}(\theta) \\
\sin^2(\sin^{-1}x) & = x^2 && \text{cancel out the 1's and divide by} -1 \\
\sin(\sin^{-1}x) & = x && \text{taking the square root on both sides}
\end{alignat}

Now $\sin(\sin^{-1}x)=x$ holds because of the cancellation laws, but for that you will need to have the interval $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, as there is nothing said about this interval I'm wondering if the prove still holds the way I did it.

Comment: $\sin^{-1}x$ is only defined when $-1 \le  x \le 1$. Proof looks fine to me, although there should be backwards implication signs.

Comment: You have to explain why the answer is not $\color{red}-\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: Try drawing a diagram, where $x$ is the angle on the unit circle, $\sin x$ = opposite leg and the hypotenuse is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

First, $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is defined for $-1 \le x \le 1$. Consequently, the proof implicitly presumes that $-1 \le x \le 1$.

Second, you did not write $\iff$ in each step.

Third, your proof did not specify why $\cos^2(\sin^{-1}(x))=1-x^2 \iff \cos(\sin^{-1}(x))=\color{red}{+}\sqrt{1-x^2}$. You need to justify that by mentioning that $-\pi/2 \le \sin^{-1}(x) \le \pi/2$ and $\cos(\theta) \ge 0$ for $\theta \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest issue with your approach is that it is going in the wrong direction, and you haven't showed that your implications are reversible. What you have proved, in effect, is this: if the desired identity holds, then $\sin\bigl(\sin^{-1}x\bigr)=x$ holds. But that doesn't prove that your identity holds. After all, if $-1=\pi$ holds, then $\sin\bigl(\sin^{-1}x\bigr)=x$ holds, but we're certainly not going to claim that $-1=\pi$ anytime soon!

Remember what $\sin^{-1}x$ actually means: the unique $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ such that $\sin\theta=x$ (if any such $\theta$ exists). Of course, we should assume $x\in[-1,1]$ in order for the expression "$\sin^{-1}x$" to make any sense in this context. Now, in the case that $|x|=1,$ then clearly we have $\theta=\pm\pi/2,$ so that $\cos(\theta)=0=\sqrt{1-x^2}.$ For other cases, we use the right triangle with one vertex at the origin, another on the unit circle below the $y$-axis with $x$ as the (natural) $x$-coordinate, and the right angle on the negative $y$-axis. Letting $\theta$ be the acute angle at the origin, counterclockwise from the negative $y$-axis, we have readily by construction (and right angle trigonometry) that $\theta=\sin^{-1}x,$ and the $y$-coordinate of the vertex on the unit circle is $\cos\bigl(\sin^{-1}x\bigr),$ whence the Pythagorean Theorem proves the desired identity.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$\tag1
\cos^2y = 1 - \sin^2y$$
Applied substitution
$$y = \sin^{-1}x$$
We have
\begin{align}
\tag2\cos^2(\sin^{-1}x) &= 1 - \sin^2(\sin^{-1}x)\\
\tag3 &= 1 - x^2
\end{align}
Therefore
$$\tag4 \big|\cos(\sin^{-1}x)\big| =  \sqrt{1 - x^2}$$

**Note**: For $\frac{-\pi}{2} \leq y \leq \frac{\pi}{2},\,\cos(y)$ is always non-negative $\implies\cos(\sin^{-1}x) =  \sqrt{1 - x^2}$

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, simple but clear to me. Just want to make sure, but $\frac{-\pi}{2} \leq y \leq \frac{\pi}{2},\,\cos(y)$ could give me a $0$ as well right, so shouldn't it be non-negative then instead of always positive?

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I have already modified the answer.